# foreach loop not showing result clear in haversine formula

Tags: php, laravel

My code is like that

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
                $center_lat = $lat;
                $center_lng = $lon;
                $lat=$vehicle->lat;
                $lng=$vehicle->lon;

                $distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);
                print_r($distance);  
            }
return response()->json([$vehicles,$distance]);
```

it results me this

```
3326.223273082541.763216161968[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            .....
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            .....
        }
    ]
]
```

As you can see distance is not clear i want my output like this

```
distance from this vehicle:3326.2232730825
[
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                .....
            },
distance from this vehicle:41.763216161968
            {
                "id": 3,
                .....
            }
        ]
    ]
```

I want every distance along with vehicle object in json so it will be readable

Answer (score 1):

You can add the distance into the vehicle data, or just create a new result with this data combined in the loop...

```
$output = [];
foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) {
    $center_lat = $lat;
    $center_lng = $lon;
    $lat=$vehicle->lat;
    $lng=$vehicle->lon;

    // Add distance into temporary vehicle array
    $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);

    // Add the combined data to an output array
    $output [$key] = $vehicle;
}
// Output new array as result
return response()->json($output);
```

Comment: it shows me "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" in $vehicle['distance]

Comment: You ned to use `$vehicle->distance ` instead of the previous `$vehicle['distance']`

Comment: Undefined variable: key

Comment: You mean in `foreach ($vehicles as $key =>`?

Comment: can we merge more arrays in that array?

Comment: Depends on the arrays, how they link in with the data.

Comment: i want to add same array as vehicle in my code .just use foreign key from vehicle array and merge another array

Comment: You can use the same idea, `$vehicle->otherData = ...`.  If there are several parts to the other data though, you may be better off asking a new question with more in depth details.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do with [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```php
$output = array_map(function ($vehicle) use ($lat, $lon) {
  $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance(
    $lat, $lon, $vehicle->lat, $vehicle->lon, 6371);
  return $vehicle;
}, $vehicles->toArray());

return response()->json($output);
```

The output would be something like this:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            .....
            "distance": 3326.2232730825
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            .....
            "distance": 41.763216161968
        }
    ]
```

*Note:* The above code assumbed the variable `$vehicles` is an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections). If not, change `$vehicles->toArray()` to `iterator_to_array($vehicles)` should work.

Comment: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: If `$vehicle` is an Eloquent query result, you can use the `toArray()` method to turn it into array type so it can be used against `array_map`. I've updated my code for that.

Comment: If it is some other Iterator implementations, you may use [iterator_to_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php).

Comment: Or you could use a `foreach` which is actually faster and more direct.

Comment: I'd argue that the array_map approach is more readable, provides better variable scoping and easier to maintain. The performance difference, unless you're talking about a huge collection (i.e. 10,000+ records), is neglectable.

Comment: In this case, easier to maintain is very debatable, as for scope - all you are doing here is passing in 2 values which are used as part of a calculation and no local values are used which may leak out into the surrounding scope.  As for performance - how do you know how this code is being used, it may be called 100's of times.

Comment: There is no extra variables because I ditched them ($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng) for clarity. And I expect there can be further calculations to each item than the distance calculation. As we both don't know how this code is being used, I'd prioritize future maintenance to performance. Anyway, this is a matter of taste and I don't mean to argue an absolute "correctness".